# package BottomNavigationView does not exist

Tags: java, android

So I'm working in Android Studio (2.3.1) and I created a Bottom Navigation Activity, but I keep getting an error saying that the BottomNavigationView does not exist or cannot be found.

```
     Error:(5, 37) error: cannot find symbol class BottomNavigationView
     Error:(14, 33) error: package BottomNavigationView does not exist
     Error:(15, 39) error: package BottomNavigationView does not exist
     Error:(41, 9) error: cannot find symbol class BottomNavigationView
     Error:(41, 44) error: cannot find symbol class BottomNavigationView
     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
     > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, first time posting here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the right dependency in the app level build.gradle?

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Look at [this link](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android) for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

At your **build.gradle (Module:app)** add this line of code:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Google added BottomNavigationView in version 25.0.0, so the required dependency is `com.android.support:design:25.0.0` which you might be missing.

For more information visit [Official Android BottomNavigationView page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you copy my answer?

Comment: @SeanStayn That's not called copying your answer my friend. Though one question may have more than one answer but in this case it has just one answer and you gave it first, that's good but I think my answer has a little more details than yours which is why I wrote the answer. Hope this clarifies your doubt! :)

Answer (score 1):

I met a relay dumb situation that I had used the 25 level SDK but it still says that after a full sync and rebuilt. So I add this manual import to my Java file and the error was finally gone.

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You should migrate to **androidx** package:

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01
```

You can find here the mappings between the old support package and the new android package: [AndroidX Migration](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)